# Like + relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

Is the following sentence correct?

> Just like a girl who has crushes on good looking people, I have crushes on good looking people.

If I omit the "who has a crush on good looking people," in the first clause, then I will just be compared to any girl. So does my sentence make any sense?

Comment: This is a request for writing advice (off topic). For more information about this site please see http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "Like a girl who has crushes on good looking people, I too fall for good looking people." (or I too fall for such people).

Comment: Just like a commentator who makes comments, I am making a comment.